# How to hook system calls of my android app (non rooted device)

Tags: android, hook, system-calls, function-interposition, library-interposition

I am trying to intercept all system calls made by my Android app on a non rooted device.

So every time my app writes/reads a file, I want to intercept the system call and encrypt/decrypt the stream for security purposes. The encryption part is no problem, but how do I intercept the system calls?

Because parts of the app are modules developed by third party providers of which I can not change the source code, there is no other way to make sure that data is  stored securely.

Since I do not have root access I cannot access the address of the system call table as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114343/android-system-call-hooking) and I can not do this through an LKM module as well.

I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Edit:

Ok I got the code link form Simone Margaritelli to work now! the reason why my code kept crashing is because i had to set the right memory access permisions:

```
uint32_t page_size = getpagesize();
uint32_t entry_page_start = reloc& (~(page_size - 1));
mprotect((uint32_t *)entry_page_start, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE);
```

Comment: I need the solution of exactly similar question.

Comment: @John did you get any working approach?

Comment: @IndraYadav No I have not. Sadly I have not gotten any new suggestions I could try out. May be with an up vote this question will get more attention.

Comment: Hi, tried your suggestion but I am not able to get it working. Please see the detailed query [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101984/how-to-hook-system-calls-of-my-android-app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.it/2013/01/android-hacking-hooking-system.html) is how you can hook syscalls on Android without root permissions ( only working for your own process of course, this is not system wide ).

Comment: Yes, this is actually exactly what I was looking for. Sadly my app always crashes when trying to run the code. I have tried contacting the owner of the blog, unsuccessfully.

Comment: This blog code is not working in android 6.0 OS. Linker.h member are private in 6.0 OS. Any workaround then please let me know. I ask to owner of this blog but no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference [Suterusu](http://poppopret.org/2013/01/07/suterusu-rootkit-inline-kernel-function-hooking-on-x86-and-arm/). But it's not thread safe, and I'm also trying to find a thread safe solution.